# Jquery select based on radio button value

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, radio-button

I've looked through about 10 similar questions, but haven't found a solution to my situation. I'm not sure if my problem is in the selector, the way I'm testing "if", or the way I'm trying to show/hide the field.

I want to hide the input where name="wpbpp_settings[slideshowSpeed]" if the value of the radio button name="wpbpp_settings[slideshow]"is "false"

Here's my form:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <h2>WP Blossom PuckPros Theme Options</h2>

    <form method="post" action="options.php">

        <?php settings_fields('wpbpp_settings_group'); ?>

        <h4><?php _e('Excerpt Length for Wide Page Slider', 'wpbpp_domain'); ?></h4>
        <p>
            <label class="description" for="wpbpp_settings[excerpt_length]"><?php _e('Enter the excerpt length (number of words)', 'wpbpp_domain'); ?></label>
            <input id="wpbpp_settings[excerpt_length]" name="wpbpp_settings[excerpt_length]" type="number" min="20" max="55" step="1" value="<?php echo $wpbpp_options['excerpt_length']; ?>"/>
        </p>

        <h4><?php _e('Settings for Wide Slider', 'wpbpp_domain'); ?></h4>

        <?php
           if (!isset($wpbpp_options['slideshow'])) {

           $wpbpp_options['slideshow']='false';
               }

        ?>

        <p>
            <label class="description" for="wpbpp_settings[slideshow]"><?php _e('Do you want the slider to advance automatically?', 'wpbpp_domain'); ?></label>
            <input id="wpbpp_settings[slideshow]1" name="wpbpp_settings[slideshow]" type="radio" <?php if($wpbpp_options['slideshow'] == 'true') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> value="true" />Yes
            <input id="wpbpp_settings[slideshow]2" name="wpbpp_settings[slideshow]" type="radio" <?php if($wpbpp_options['slideshow'] == 'false') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> value="false" />No

         </p>
         <p>   
            <label class="description" for="wpbpp_settings[slideshowSpeed]"><?php _e('How often do you want the slider to advance (number of seconds)?', 'wpbpp_domain'); ?></label>
            <input id="wpbpp_settings[slideshowSpeed]" name="wpbpp_settings[slideshowSpeed]" type="number" min="1" max="8" step="1" value="<?php echo $wpbpp_options['slideshowSpeed']; ?>"/>
        </p>

        <p class="submit">
            <input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php _e('Save Options', 'wpbpp_domain'); ?>" />
        </p>

    </form>

</div>
```

and my jquery:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  togglefields();

  $('input:radio[name="wpbpp_settings[slideshow]"]').val().change(function() { togglefields(); });
});   


  function togglefields() { 
   if ($('input:radio[name="wpbpp_settings[slideshow]"].prop("checked", true)').val() =="true") {
      $('input:radio[name="wpbpp_settings[slideshowSpeed]"]').show();
    } else {
       $('input:radio[name="wpbpp_settings[slideshowSpeed]"]').hide();
    }   

</script>
```

__*_*__*_*_  EDIT ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*____**

So now I've got in closer. My problem is that my "if" statement always evaluates to "true".

Here's the revised jquery:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  togglefields();

  $('input[name="wpbpp_settings[slideshow]"]').change(function(){ togglefields() });

});   

  function togglefields() { 
   if (jQuery('input[name="wpbpp_settings[slideshow]"]').val() =="true") {
      jQuery('input[name="wpbpp_settings[slideshowSpeed]"]').show();
      alert ('show');
    } else {
       jQuery('input[name="wpbpp_settings[slideshowSpeed]"]').hide();
       alert ('hide');

    }   
   }
</script>
```

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket.

Comment: `.val().change(` you say? `.val()` doesn't contain a `change` method - that should be listed in the console...check the console!

Comment: @pmandell I reflected these changes and a bit more but still have problems with the if statement. See revised problem definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try logging `jQuery('input[name="wpbpp_settings[slideshow]"]').val()` into the console. and see if you are making the right comparison. Your approach should be:

1. Select the radio button group with `name="wpbpp_settings[slideshow]"`
2. Find the checked button for that group
3. Find its value
4. Compare and do whatever you want to

   `var selectedButton=$("input[name='wpbpp_settings[slideshow]']"]:checked");
   var value = selectedButton.val();`

or even as,

```
var selectedValue = $("input[name='wpbpp_settings[slideshow]']"]:checked").val();
```

See what you get in `selectedValue` and then make further comparisons.

Comment: I took me awhile to see how to build in your suggestion, but I finally got it fixed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the checked property of the radio button. `.val()` does not fetch you that.

Instead check for the property

```
// This would give you info whether the radio is checked or not
  if (jQuery('input[name="wpbpp_settings[slideshow]"]').is(':checked')) {
```